# excanvas.js not working on IE with dynamic load script

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer, excanvas

I am dynamically loading script to the document by using jQuery `$.getScript()` method like, `$.getScript("excanvas.js", function(data){});`

On create canvas I applied following statement for canvas,

```
var canvasDiv = document.createElement('canvas');
canvasDiv.setAttribute("width", canvasBounds.width+"px");
canvasDiv.setAttribute("height", canvasBounds.height+"px");
if(window.G_vmlCanvasManager){
    canvasDiv = G_vmlCanvasManager.initElement(canvasDiv);
}
```

and I try to draw a line on canvas, it is not working.

If I load the excanvas.js in script tag its working fine. that is like

```
<head>
<script src="excanvas.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
```

I cant find the reason. Can any one suggest a solution?

Answer (score 2):

i have used it and it works for me:

```
if ($.browser.msie) {
      G_vmlCanvasManager.initElement(canvasDiv);
}
```

After doing the top step, get the context of the canvas:

```
context = canvasDiv.getContext('2d');
```

Now draw the line using the `context` variable.

Comment: Thanks for your replay. Its working fine for me by including excanvas.js in script tag in head section. But not working while attach excanvas.js at run time.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to load excanvas asynchronously/conditionally, it *is* possible.

First, [as the instructions state](https://code.google.com/p/explorercanvas/wiki/Instructions), the canvas element(s) can't exist on the page until **AFTER** excanvas has loaded & initialized, so consider generating them or loading them asynchronously afterwards.

Once the excanvas library has loaded (via jQuery, requirejs, whatever), call this:

```
G_vmlCanvasManager.init_(document);
```

This calls the manager's internal init function that normally listens for document ready (which has usually already fired).